# How to enable "Content Handlers" for RestSharp deserializer in IIS Express?

Tags: .net, json, iis-express, restsharp

I need help with a problem and I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

I have a .NET(not CORE) web application that works as expected in one computer, but not in a second computer. Both computers are running Windows 10 and I'm testing in IISExpress 10.

At this point, I re-created the app from scratch to be identical in both computers. Dependencies, config files, packages, plugins, etc... Everything is identical.

The problem is related to an API call that I'm making using RestSharp. In debug mode, I inspected the "RestClient" configuration/options once it gets instantiated and there are some differences.

In the first computer, the "RestClient" instance includes the "AcceptTypes, ContentHandlers and Serializers" parameters.
[image]

In the second computer, those options/parameters are missing altogether. So when I run the app I get an exception like this:[image]

And the response in the debugger looks like this:
[image]

So, given that as far as I can tell everything is identical, how come the "RestClient" gets instantiated differently? And how do I get the instance of the "RestClient" to include "AcceptTypes, ContentHandlers and Serializer" by default?

The ONLY difference between the two computers I'm using is that the one that fails to make the API call is behind a proxy. I've looked into that issue as well, but everything I've done to change the configuration of IISExpress hasn't worked either.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are looking at different objects, so I don't expect them to be the same. Besides, the second obviously shows a connection error, so I wonder why you didn't focus on that first.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li - I'm not looking at different objects. Just posted a screen shot of a request object that works, and a screen shot of a failed response object.
And, i'm not focusing on the failed response, because the code that generates the request is the same, but works in one computer and not the other. Process of elimination brings me to how the request is instantiated.